# Add Text Alternative if Not insert data in Form

Tags: php

How do I fill in the result by default before users enter details of their data.
For example my php code is like this

```
<b>Address:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($dnn['you_address'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

If before the user fill in the form of address, how do I display the default information.
 For example

**Address:** Address has not added

Comment: @latif - yes. input in form

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript or Jquery. If use PHP only you will get result after you run submit form.
If you want to showing result before run submit form. You can use Javascript like alert below.

```
<script>
function check(){
if(document.getElementById('address').value==''){
alert("Address has not added");
}
```

And in your address input give `id = "address"` and `onkeypress="check()"`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use placeholder!

```
<input type="text" name="you_address" placeholder="Address has not added" value="<?php echo htmlentities($dnn['you_address'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As in this [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/3x0h-mayb) -*hit "run" or F9 to execute*- something like this

```
<?php
$defVal = 'default input';
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test-input" value="<?php echo $defVal?>">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $_POST['test-input'];
    }
?>
```